# How to call different ajax call with onload and onclick in jquery using fuction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a simple ajax call on load and onclick,I am using function for it.Here my ajax call url is different onload and onclick,I have used function and different parameter but its still showing previous json using onclick. Below is my code,
Updated in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/YOeklbX5shZCnHVRktyK?p=preview

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="critical">
 <span id="name1"></span> : <span id="value1"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="major">
 <span id="name2"></span> : <span id="value2"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="minor">
 <span id="name3"></span> : <span id="value3"></span>
 </div>
<button>click</button>
```

### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.reload_cart = function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "1.json",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#name1").text(result.critical[0].name);
            $("#value1").text(result.critical[0].value);

            $("#name2").text(result.major[0].name);
            $("#value2").text(result.major[0].value);

            $("#name3").text(result.minor[0].name);
            $("#value3").text(result.minor[0].value);
        }
    });
  }
 $.fn.reload_cart(); 
    $("button").click(function(){
        var url2;
        $.fn.reload_cart(url2); 
        url2: "2.json";
    });
});
```

### 1.json

```
{
    "critical": [{
        "name": "critical",
        "value": "50"
    }],
    "major": [{
        "name": "major",
        "value": "40"
    }],
    "minor": [{
        "name": "minor",
        "value": "20"
    }]
}
```

### 2.json

```
{
    "critical": [{
        "name": "criticalnew",
        "value": "53"
    }],
    "major": [{
        "name": "majornew",
        "value": "43"
    }],
    "minor": [{
        "name": "minornew",
        "value": "23"
    }]
}
```

Comment: `$.fn.reload_cart = function()` doesn't accept a parameter as you've written it.

Comment: It always load data from 1.json. I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `json` file name in `reload_cart()` function and check if file name is passed then read from this file(1.json) else read from another file(2.json). Please your `javascript` code to following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.reload_cart = function(url){
  if(!url){
     url = "1.json"
  }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#name1").text(result.critical[0].name);
            $("#value1").text(result.critical[0].value);

            $("#name2").text(result.major[0].name);
            $("#value2").text(result.major[0].value);

            $("#name3").text(result.minor[0].name);
            $("#value3").text(result.minor[0].value);
        }
    });
  }
 $.fn.reload_cart(); 
    $("button").click(function(){
        var url2 = "2.json";
        $.fn.reload_cart(url2);
    });
});
```

I have updated your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qHKNcVrvgU7a2OII7GHE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `reload_cart` function accept a parameter `url`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.reload_cart = function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#name1").text(result.critical[0].name);
        $("#value1").text(result.critical[0].value);

        $("#name2").text(result.major[0].name);
        $("#value2").text(result.major[0].value);

        $("#name3").text(result.minor[0].name);
        $("#value3").text(result.minor[0].value);
      }
    });
  }
  $.fn.reload_cart("1.json");
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.fn.reload_cart("2.json");
  });
});
```